# How to query (filter) a Julia DataFrame when some keys have NA values?

Tags: linq, dataframe, julia

How to query (filter) a Julia DataFrame when some filters may be explicitly ask for a NA value ?

E.g.

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
       a = ["aa", "bb","zz", "cc","cc"],
       b = [1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
       v = [12,13,14,15,16]
)

df[3,1]  = NA
df[5,2]  = NA

5×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a    │ b  │ v  │
├─────┼──────┼────┼────┤
│ 1   │ "aa" │ 1  │ 12 │
│ 2   │ "bb" │ 2  │ 13 │
│ 3   │ NA   │ 2  │ 14 │
│ 4   │ "cc" │ 3  │ 15 │
│ 5   │ "cc" │ NA │ 16 │
```

Neither of these two approach work:

```
# From DataFramesMeta.jl..
test = @where(:b .== 2, :a .== NA)

# From Query.jl..
x = @from i in df begin
    @where (i.a == "cc") && (i.b == NA)
    @select {i.a,i.b,i.v}
    @collect DataFrame
end
```

The problem is that I'll have to put this into a function where I don't know *a priori* if the parameters requested to filter are actual values or NAs, so to use isna() I would need to biforcate any single filter parameter..

Answer (score 1):

I learned that both `(NA == NA)` and `(NA == everythingelse)` both returns `NA` values instead of the expected boolean ones.

To get the expected behaviour (and use the comparison to query dataframes where `NA` values are either present or requested for) one can use `isequal(a,b)`, e.g.:

```
test = @where(df, isequal.(:a,"cc"), isequal.(:b,NA) ) #from DataFramesMeta.jl
```

Comment: The Query.jl docs are really not very informative about how to deal with NAs

Comment: You could write `test = @where(df, :a.== "cc", :b .=== NA)` because NA is singleton (See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/object.html ) and you could check identity with singleton.

Comment: Or `test = @where(df, :a.== "cc", :b .≡ NA)` ( "≡" can be typed by \equiv<tab> )